# Fast scrolling DataGridView losing text in cell drawn with RowPrePaint event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I added "RowPrePaint" event to my DataGridView which is adding row number in the first cell of every row.
In case when DataGrid has a lot of elements (a couple thousands), and I am scrolling DataGrid fast (keep scroll with the mouse left click and pull down and up fast), I do not see text in that cell (looks like the cells are empty). 
With the slow scrolling it works correct.

Note: I also have check box column beside the row number column. After one "click" on any check box in the DataGrid, problem is not appear. Somehow that one click refresh all cells and text is always visible, even with the fast scrolling.

Is there anyone have idea what is the problem in the first case above ?

Comment: I think data grid view doesn't update all the cells when user is scrolling up and down for performance.

Comment: One click on any checkbox in the DataGridView is making that text in cells is visible all the time. That click  somehow refreshes all cells.